# Find/Cut string from first integer in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm stuck with a problem, in my database i've values like this:

GSB45-B,
GSBD60-01,
etc.

Now i need to get the values **GSB** / **GSBD** out of these strings. So in fact i need te first character from te start to the first integer.

Hopefully someone can help me, thanks from now.

Comment: So you want `45-B` and `60-01` ?

Comment: No, i need GSB, GSBD. (the chars till the first integrer). Thanks.

Comment: @Ronn0 : Could you please check my answer and let me know if that is fine with you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit of a clunky solution, but you can try:

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, '-', 1), '0', ''), '1', ''), '2', ''), '3', ''), '4', ''), '5', ''), '6', ''), '7', ''), '8', ''), '9', '') AS extracted
FROM
    yourtbl
```

Comment: Great! I'm glad that it works and you only need to run it once! I'm sure many others will laugh hysterically at first sight of all those `REPLACE`s, but it's really the only way you can do it AFAIK! =)

Answer (score 1):

How about this??

```
SELECT 
  myWord, 
  SUBSTR(myWord,1,LEAST (
    if (Locate('0',myWord) >0,Locate('0',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('1',myWord) >0,Locate('1',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('2',myWord) >0,Locate('2',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('3',myWord) >0,Locate('3',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('4',myWord) >0,Locate('4',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('5',myWord) >0,Locate('5',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('6',myWord) >0,Locate('6',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('7',myWord) >0,Locate('7',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('8',myWord) >0,Locate('8',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('9',myWord) >0,Locate('9',myWord),999)
  )-1) as NewString
FROM myTable;
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6bb8a/1)

***Also read, [Using alias name in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11156563/using-alias-name-in-another-column). This is same question as yours.***

Comment: Unfortunately, `REGEXP` only returns `0` or `1` based on if it matched the pattern or not, not the extracted match. As a result, your `LOCATE()` will only be able to return `0` or `-1`, not the index of the first number.

Comment: No, because the value passed to `LOCATE()` will only be a boolean `0` or `1`, not the index of the first occurrence of a number as you would intuitively expect. It's a shame that MySQL doesn't support extracting strings based on patterns...

Comment: They both give:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REGEXP '[0-9]')-1) AS 'the_string' FROM products LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1.

Comment: @FahimParkar SQL Fiddle is back now, btw.  Sorry about the outage!

Answer (score 1):

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE FUNCTION digits( str CHAR(32) ) RETURNS CHAR(32)
BEGIN
  DECLARE i, len SMALLINT DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE ret CHAR(32) DEFAULT '';
  DECLARE c CHAR(1);
  SET len = CHAR_LENGTH( str );
  label1: LOOP
  REPEAT
    BEGIN
      SET c = MID( str, i, 1 );
      IF c BETWEEN '0' AND '9' THEN 
        SET ret=SUBSTRING( str, 1, i-1);

        LEAVE label1;
      END IF;
      SET i = i + 1;
    END;
  UNTIL i > len END REPEAT;
  END LOOP label1;
  RETURN ret;
END |
DELIMITER ;

select digits('GSB45-B'),digits('GSBD60-01') ,digits('KKGSBD60-01') ;
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL can't do REGEXP extraction, and that's a really sad thing :(

Assuming that the pattern of your values is `[A-Z]*[0-9]{2}-.*` you can use this ugly thing:

```
SELECT
    LEFT(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX("GSB45-B", "-", 1),
        LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX("GSB45-B", "-", 1)) - 2
    ) as CODE;
```

But I would recommand doing your parsing on the application side :)

Comment: what if string is `GSB4543-B`? Isn't your code will change to `- 4`

Comment: This almost worked, but i did post a bad example. There are also codes with 3 digits GSBD603-03. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Indeed Fahim Parkar, that's why I made the assumption on the pattern :)