# Using alias name in another column

Tags: mysql, alias

This question is extended part of my previous question, 
***[Finding number position in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135464/finding-number-position-in-string/11155594#11155594).***

I have table `myTable` as below (myWord ==> varchar(10))

```
++++++++++++
+ myWord   +    
++++++++++++
+ AB123    +
+ A413     +
+ X5231    +
+ ABE921   +
+ 15231    +
+ 523      +
+ ABC      +
++++++++++++
```

What I wanted is as below.

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ myWord   + myPos + NewString +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ AB123    + 3     + AB        +
+ A413     + 2     + A         +
+ X5231    + 2     + X         +
+ ABE921   + 4     + ABE       +
+ 15231    + 1     +           +
+ 523      + 1     +           +
+ ABC      + 999   + ABC       +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

To get above output, I used below query.

```
SELECT 
  myWord, 
  LEAST (
    if (Locate('0',myWord) >0,Locate('0',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('1',myWord) >0,Locate('1',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('2',myWord) >0,Locate('2',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('3',myWord) >0,Locate('3',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('4',myWord) >0,Locate('4',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('5',myWord) >0,Locate('5',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('6',myWord) >0,Locate('6',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('7',myWord) >0,Locate('7',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('8',myWord) >0,Locate('8',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('9',myWord) >0,Locate('9',myWord),999)
  ) as myPos,
  if (LEAST (
    if (Locate('0',myWord) >0,Locate('0',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('1',myWord) >0,Locate('1',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('2',myWord) >0,Locate('2',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('3',myWord) >0,Locate('3',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('4',myWord) >0,Locate('4',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('5',myWord) >0,Locate('5',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('6',myWord) >0,Locate('6',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('7',myWord) >0,Locate('7',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('8',myWord) >0,Locate('8',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('9',myWord) >0,Locate('9',myWord),999)
  )=999,myWord,SUBSTR(myWord,1,LEAST (
    if (Locate('0',myWord) >0,Locate('0',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('1',myWord) >0,Locate('1',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('2',myWord) >0,Locate('2',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('3',myWord) >0,Locate('3',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('4',myWord) >0,Locate('4',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('5',myWord) >0,Locate('5',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('6',myWord) >0,Locate('6',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('7',myWord) >0,Locate('7',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('8',myWord) >0,Locate('8',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('9',myWord) >0,Locate('9',myWord),999)
  )-1)) as NewString
FROM myTable;
```

### My Question Is

After giving name to column as **MyPos**, why I can't use that name in another column as shown in below query?

```
SELECT 
  myWord, 
  LEAST (
    if (Locate('0',myWord) >0,Locate('0',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('1',myWord) >0,Locate('1',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('2',myWord) >0,Locate('2',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('3',myWord) >0,Locate('3',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('4',myWord) >0,Locate('4',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('5',myWord) >0,Locate('5',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('6',myWord) >0,Locate('6',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('7',myWord) >0,Locate('7',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('8',myWord) >0,Locate('8',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('9',myWord) >0,Locate('9',myWord),999)
  ) as myPos,
  if (myPos=999,myWord,SUBSTR(myWord,1,myPos-1)) as NewString
FROM myTable;
```

But, this gives me error as

```
Unknown column 'myPos' in 'field list':
```

### [See here for more details](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53542/11)

***Please suggest me what can be done to make this query shorter by using alias name***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting the least part as a subselect. That you can alias.

Something like this:

```
SELECT 
  mytable.myWord, 
  myPos.l,
  if (l=999,mytable.myWord,SUBSTR(mytable.myWord,1,l-1)) as NewString
FROM myTable, 
(select myword, LEAST (
    if (Locate('0',myWord) >0,Locate('0',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('1',myWord) >0,Locate('1',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('2',myWord) >0,Locate('2',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('3',myWord) >0,Locate('3',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('4',myWord) >0,Locate('4',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('5',myWord) >0,Locate('5',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('6',myWord) >0,Locate('6',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('7',myWord) >0,Locate('7',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('8',myWord) >0,Locate('8',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('9',myWord) >0,Locate('9',myWord),999)
  ) as l from mytable)
as myPos
where myPos.myword = mytable.myword
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53542/24)

Comment: sql fiddle is showing me many rows & not giving me what is expected

Comment: great & thanks a ton... I also did some RND. See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea7e3/6)

Comment: Any inputs on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155690/use-of-regex-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Based on @juergend answer, I also tried with below and its working too.

```
SELECT 
  t1.myWord, t2.l as MyPos, if (t2.l=999,t1.myWord,SUBSTR(t1.myWord,1,t2.l-1)) as NewString
FROM myTable t1 JOIN  
(select id, LEAST (
    if (Locate('0',myWord) >0,Locate('0',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('1',myWord) >0,Locate('1',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('2',myWord) >0,Locate('2',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('3',myWord) >0,Locate('3',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('4',myWord) >0,Locate('4',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('5',myWord) >0,Locate('5',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('6',myWord) >0,Locate('6',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('7',myWord) >0,Locate('7',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('8',myWord) >0,Locate('8',myWord),999),
    if (Locate('9',myWord) >0,Locate('9',myWord),999)
  ) as l from mytable) as t2
 ON t1.id=t2.id;
```

**NOTE** : For this I have added `id` in table to JOIN two tables.

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea7e3/9)