# Mysql Query Request

Tags: mysql

Straight to the point and this might be very simple for some of you.

I have a simple SELECT query (select description from table) which produces all i want like below :

```
 - testword123
 - testword875
 - myjob1 45
 - myjob is 544
```

What i need is to have as a result :

```
 - testword
 - myjob
```

I can use a `SELECT distinct LEFT(description,8)` which works fine, but the problem is not ALL 'description' have the same number of words :-(

So basically, what i want is retrieve ONLY the letters from the 'description' result set.

Thanks!!

R

Comment: SELECT distinct LEFT(description,8) wouldn't work for the example provided above. Can you provide a more realistic/representative data set?

Comment: >but the problem is not ALL 'description' have the same number of words
That is the problem. You might want to look into your database design.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134452/find-cut-string-from-first-integer-in-mysql

Comment: Thanks "undefined_variable" - Your solution 
"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134452/find-cut-string-from-first-integer-in-mysql"
was the correct one!! (y) (with a little bit of tweaking, this helped A LOT)
A+++

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT distinct LEFT(description, charindex(' ', description) - 1)
```

Depending on your implementation, it might be possible to declare 'description' as a variable beforehand so you don't have to type it twice in the same query.

Answer (score 0):

There are two decisions: 
1) Handle each decription in PHP
or
2) Handle user input before writing it to DB. Add field to table as index of first not letter symbol and then use it in LEFT mysql function

Answer (score 0):

Thanks "undefined_variable" - Your solution "stackoverflow.com/questions/11134452/…; was the correct one!! (y) (with a little bit of tweaking, this helped A LOT) A+++